# Is the order of iteration for javascript array methods (map, forEach, reduce, etc) deterministic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, specifications, deterministic

Is the order of iterating through an array using one of the native methods (map, forEach, reduce, filter, etc) deterministic and guaranteed by the standard?

EG, are foo, bar, baz, and qux guaranteed to be `[0, 2, 6, 12]`?

```
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const foo = a.map((item, index) => item * index);
const bar = []; a.forEach((item, index) => bar[index] = item * index);
const baz = []; a.reduce((total, item, index) => baz[index] = item * index, 0);
const qux = []; a.filter((item, index) => qux[index] = item * index);
// etc
```

(These are (very) contrived examples)

Comment: Yes, the numeric properties are traversed in ascending order. It's explicitly described in the language spec.

Comment: btw, you need to use a start value for reduce, like `a.reduce((total, item, index) => baz[index] = item * index, null);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback function is called for each element present in the array, in ascending order. It is **not** called for missing elements. (Missing elements? Yes, JavaScript handle sparse arrays)

```
var test = [];
test[30] = 'Test'; // sparse array, only one element defined.

test.forEach(
  function(value){
    console.log(value); // will only be called one time.
  }
);
```

From the standard: [ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

> **22.1.3.10 Array.prototype.forEach ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )**
>
> NOTE 1
>
> *callbackfn* should be a function that accepts three arguments.
>   **forEach** calls *callbackfn* once for each element present in the array, in ascending order. *callbackfn* is called only for elements of
>   the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements
>   of the array
>
> If a *thisArg* parameter is provided, it will be used as the
>   **this** value for each invocation of *callbackfn*. If it is not provided, **undefined** is used instead.
>
> *callbackfn* is called with three arguments: the value of the
>   element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed.
>
> **forEach** does not directly mutate the object on which it is called but the object may be mutated by the calls to *callbackfn*.
>
> When the **forEach** method is called with one or two arguments, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
> 3. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is **false**, throw a **TypeError** exception.
> 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be **undefined**.
> 5. Let k be 0.
> 6. Repeat, while k < len a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k). b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(O, Pk). c. If kPresent is **true**, then i. Let kValue be
>      ? Get(O, Pk). ii. Perform ? Call(callbackfn, T, « kValue, k, O »). d.
>      Increase k by 1.
> 7. Return **undefined**.

Comment: That's `forEach`, but what about `map`?

Comment: @nog642 What do you think? Did they specify completely different algorithms for *forEach*, *map*, *every*, *some*, etc.? There is a link in my answer, to the standard, where you can read the steps taken for any standard method defined on the prototype of the array, without me copying it to an old answer.